# tool for documenting database and software changes

Tags: windows, mysql, database

I'm currently working on a php project with 3 other people. I need a free software which can help me document the changes/revisions on the database and on the application that were developing.

Comment: Maybe you want to be a bit more specific. If you are working with other people, is the revision control system you're using not enough?

Comment: Could you not just use git? Or is there some special functionality that is required?

Comment: @slotishtype: I'll try using Git, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As slhck suggests,  I would use a revision control system to record changes, whenever you check in a change you have an opportunity to type in a message stating the reason for the change.

For database structure changes I use a revision control system to manage a set of SQL DDL commands "create table ...; create index ..." which I edit whenever I make a change (even if I normally do so by "alter table" etc). This then preserves a history of changes to the database structure. I use end-of-line comments in the DDL to record the purpose of the fields.

If this is insufficient for you, you might consider editing your question to clarify what you need.